# libxml2 get xsd definition for node

Tags: xsd, libxml2

i have an .xml file and .xsd
how can i get node definition (restrictions,annotation...) from schema after parsing and validating file using libxml2?

```
xmlInitParser();
xmlSchemaPtr schema = NULL;
xmlSchemaParserCtxtPtr schema_parser_ctxt = NULL;
int has_schema_errors = 0;
int ret = -1;
xmlSchemaValidCtxtPtr valid_ctxt = NULL;
schema_parser_ctxt = xmlSchemaNewParserCtxt("test.xsd");
xmlTextReaderPtr reader = NULL;
const char* filename = "file.xml";
reader = xmlReaderForFile(filename, NULL, 0);

if (reader != NULL)
{
    if (valid_ctxt)
        xmlTextReaderSchemaValidateCtxt(reader, valid_ctxt, 0);
    ret = xmlTextReaderRead(reader);
    while (ret == 1 && !has_schema_errors)
    {
        ret = xmlTextReaderRead(reader);
        xmlNodePtr node;
        node = xmlTextReaderCurrentNode(reader);
        // here i want get node definition from xsd

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with libxml2.